# WP Query posts__in not working with array

Tags: wp-query, array

I am using the following code to generate a specific list of posts with `WP_Query`

```
$args = array (
    'post__in'   => $cookie_array,
    'post_type'  => 'tyre',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '100',
);
```

`$cookie_array` is an array I generate based on some values in a cookie (post id's). The problem is that for some reason the WP_Query won't display the post that corresponds to the last value in the array. For example if the array consists of 1,2,3 then my WP_Query only gets the posts with the id's 1 and 2.

I've printed out the values of the array, right before I call the argument list shown above and there's definitely 1 more value listed than WP_Query is getting.

Any ideas what's going on?

### Edit

As per request the result of `var_dump($cookie_array)` - to confirm only 3 items are shown through my WP_Query when the array is set as below:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "15829" [1]=> string(5) "22728" [2]=> string(5) "22734" [3]=> string(5) "22725" }
```

**`var_dump($getposts->request)` outputs:**

```
 string(230) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID IN (15829,22728,22734,22725) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'tyre' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100"
```

Comment: Can you show here your `var_dump($cookie_array);` result?

Comment: Added to original post :)

Comment: What does `var_dump($query->request)` say? (Where `$query` is your instance of `WP_Query`)

Comment: Updated OP again with var_dump($getposts->request)

Comment: And you get results when you query without the `post__in` part? And you're sure all of those posts are published posts of type 'tyre'?

Comment: Are you sure that each ID is indeed a valid, published post?